# send emacs file buffers to/from browser with Gmail message?

Tags: emacs, gmail, firefox-extensions, google-chrome-extensions

I sometimes find myself writing a Gmail email on the browser and I want to switch to editing it into my open emacs session, then once I am done, flip back to Gmail on the browser text window. Is there a good way of doing this? Maybe with a Firefox/Chrome extension?

EDIT: Ideally something that will open a new buffer in an *existing* emacs session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ljobjlafonikaiipfkggjbhkghgicgoh) Chrome extension.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Super User! Could you [edit] your answer to include a bit more information about what the chrome extension is/does?

Comment: I gave the answer to @nauhygon since I never heard before of this Chrome extension, but I would have given the answer also to `u-punkt` if it were possible.

Answer (score 1):

There is "It's all text", https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/its-all-text/, for Firefox. That extension lets you edit textarea contents in an external editor, e.g. emacsclient, and save your edits back to the textarea.